# Usage of 'and' with two clauses

Tags: conjugation

Is this sentence correct:

> Categorization could help them out with concentration and to get better results.

Complete paragraph:

> Due to fact that prerequisite conditions and educational needs are not the same for each pupil, categorization could help them out with concentration and to get better results. However that is not completely positive. For example, the opportunity to become familiar with any kinds of behavior seemed missed out on this solution.

Comment: can we have a context please?

Comment: Please wait at least a day, even better two, before you decide that an answer is the best answer you could get. If you don't you'll only ever get one point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your example is grammatical (but I'm not sure).  "And" ordinarily connects two constituents of the same category.  In your example, it connects "out with concentration" and "to get better results", but the first is not even a constituent, and the second does not have the same category(ies) as the first.

However, some (not I) think that some "and" constructions can be derived by deleting repeated words, and according to that, you could get your example from:

> Categorization could help them out with concentration, and categorization could help them to get better results.

by deleting the repeated "categorization could help them".

Comment: Then you think that 'Categorization could help them out to concentrate and to get better results' is correct?

Comment: @mehran, no, at least that doesn't sound good to me, because I don't like the "out" in "help them out to concentrate".  "Help them out" is okay, or "help them out with concentration", or "help them to concentrate".  With no "out" it's okay: "Categorization could help them to concentrate and to get better results", but that is just a conjunction of two infinitives and is not nearly as interesting as your original example.

Answer (score 0):

The example may be inelegant because it conjoins a noun (concentration) and verb (to get).
It would work well as two verbs: "Categorization could help them to concentrate and get better results."
Or two nouns: "Categorization could help them with their concentration and with better results."

The "out", in the phrase, "help them out" is not needed here. Just "help them".